# SQLAlchemy & postgres reflection: erroneously reflecting all schemas

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have my reflection configured like so:

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=db.engine, schema='web')

Base = automap_base(metadata=meta)
Base.prepare()
```

I thought the `schema` keyword would limit the reflection to the specified schema, but running the app I see that it reflects tables in all schemas anyway, which leads to some conflicts given I have tables of the same name in different schemas. So `Base.classes` will contain the wrong classes given that it uses the wrong schema.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the tables reflected in `MetaData.reflect` using the `only` keyword.

```
meta.reflect(bind=db.engine, schema='web', only=tables)
```

If you don't know the tables in the particular schema ahead of time, you can use an [`Inspector`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html?highlight=inspector#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_table_names) object to get them.

```
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(db.engine)
tables = insp.get_table_names(schema='web')
```